# @Sql in testing for populating the database in Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, testing

I am trying to test my spring controllers and for that i need to populate my database. I am using h2 database.

```
@Sql(scripts="day9_springboot/src/test/resources/article.sql")
public class ArticleControllerIT {
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate;

    //we need to mock some data for the database
    @BeforeAll
    public static void init(){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://localhost:8080/articles"));
}
}
```

This is how i try to populate it. However the script does not seem to work.

```
insert into article(id,title,author,publication_date) values(1,'Title1','author1','2010-10-10');
insert into article(id,title,author,publication_date) values(2,'Title1','author1','2010-10-10');
insert into article(id,title,author,publication_date) values(3,'Title1','author1','2010-10-10');
```

This is the script. Any suggestions on how to make this work ?

Comment: Wht is the error message? My guess is that you need to create the table "article". Here are some examples: https://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-sql-annotation-default-scripts-example.html

Comment: Could you provide more information about the estructure of the article table?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-applications) of Spring boot to run your test using Spring Test Framework.

At least you need to use `@SpringBootTest` in order to start your application. There are several annotations and helper/mocks classes to ease your tests depending on what part of Spring you want to test (MVC, data, etc...)

```
@SpringBootTest
@Sql(scripts="day9_springboot/src/test/resources/article.sql")
public class ArticleControllerIT {

    @RestTemplate restTemplate;

}
```